# Is it possible to have conditional options in ~/.ssh/config based on the calling application (ssh or sshfs)?

Tags: ssh, sshfs, ssh-config

In my ~/.ssh/config file I have the following option:

`RemoteCommand /bin/sh -c 'tmux has-session && exec tmux attach || exec tmux'`

This automatically starts tmux and connects to an existing session if possible when connecting via ssh.

This causes sshfs to fail to connect with the error `read: Connection reset by peer`.

Is there a way to apply this options selectively only when connecting with ssh and not when attempting to mount a filesystem with sshfs?

Note that I still want to load the remainder of the options in that file for sshfs, since they are still relevant.  Using `sshfs -F /dev/null` is not an option.

I could of course create two separate configuration files for ssh and sshfs, but that would require a bunch of duplication that seems unecessary.

Comment: In this case, you could change you RemoteCommand in `tty -s && tmux has-session && exec tmux attach || exec tmux `. This way the command will execute only when an interactive session is started. This will solve your example problem but it does not answer your question.

Comment: @andcoz The tutorial that I lifted the `RemoteCommand` from actually specified to set `RequestTTY yes` as well, so I'm not sure that would help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you used a different hostname when you want to use `tmux` eg

for sshfs :

```
ssh user@remotehost
```

but for tmux

```
ssh user@remotehost_tmux
```

and then in your `~/.ssh/config` have a section specific for the host `remotehost_tmux`

eg.

```
# Global Options
#UseRoaming no

# Hostname specific options
Host <hostname>_tmux
     RemoteCommand /bin/sh -c 'tmux has-session && exec tmux attach || exec tmux'
Hostname <hostname>
#
```